# Rewrite Rules: Am I doing it right?

Tags: php, .htaccess

OK, so using some other threads I found, I was able to (I think) piece this together.

I want to dynamically have **site.com/lesson/41**, for example, redirect to **site.com/shop/lessons_detail.php?id=41**

Here's my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule    ^/shop/lessons_detail.php?id=([0-9]+)/?$    lesson/$1    [NC,L]
```

Before I unleash it and cause untold chaos (there are well over 600 of these that need to happen), I wanted to make sure I got it right and understood the syntax. Thanks for checking. :)

Comment: Can't you test it in a test environment or your localhost?

Comment: no, not at the moment. but thanks for the idea - i will try this when i get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the rule and the page it rewrites to reversed.  Your regex is supposed to match the URL people see/type the `.php?id=` is the internal representation (how your server reads it).  So it should be something like this ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule)):

```
RewriteRule    ^/lesson/([0-9]+)?$    /shop/lessons_detail.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was a little confused. Will try this out later on. Appreciate the advice and the link!